# Are Constant Time and Amortized Constant Time effectively considered equivalent?

Tags: algorithms, complexity

I need to write a RandomQueue that allows for appends and random removal in Constant Time ( O(1) ).

My first thought was to back it with some kind of Array (I chose an ArrayList), since arrays have constant access via an index.

Looking over the documentation though, I realized that ArrayLists' additions are considered Amortized Constant Time, since an addition may require a reallocation of the underlying array, which is O(n).

Are Amortized Constant Time and Constant Time effectively the same, or do I need to look at some structure thay doesn't require a full reallocation on every addition?

I'm asking this because array based structures aside (which as far as I know will always have Amortized Constant Time additions), I can't think of anything that will meet the requirements:

- Anything tree based will have at best O(log n) access
- A linked list could potentially have O(1) additions (if a reference to the tail is kept), but a random removal should be at best O(n).

Here's the full question; in case I glazed over some important details:

> Design and implement a RandomQueue. This is an implementation of the Queue interface in which the remove() operation removes an element that is chosen uniformly at random among all the elements currently in the queue. (Think of a RandomQueue as a bag in which we can add elements or reach in and blindly remove some random element.) The add(x) and remove() operations in a RandomQueue should run in constant time per operation.

Comment: Does the assignment specify how random removals are performed? Are you given an index to remove or a reference to a queue element?

Comment: It doesn't give any specifics. The requirements are just a structure that implements the Queue interface and has O(1) additions and removals.

Comment: As an aside – a resizeable array with O(n) growing does not necessarily have O(1) addition: this depends on *how* we grow the array. Growing by a constant amount *a* is still O(n) for addition (we have an `1/a` chance for an O(n) operation), but growing by a constant factor `a > 1` is O(1) amortized for addition: we have a `(1/a)^n` chance of an O(n) operation, but that probability approaches zero for large `n`.

Comment: ArrayLists use the latter correct?

Comment: Yes, the `add(x)` method of Java's `ArrayList` type is guaranteed to run in amortized constant time.

Comment: The author of the question (me) was thinking of the amortized constant time solution. I'll clarify that in the next edition.  (Although worst-case constant-time can be achieved here using the technique of [de-amortization](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-68535-9_4).)

Comment: @PatMorin Well, hi Pat. What are the chances? And thank you. I guess I couldn't hope for a better answer! And, if I could add something to the revision list: could you please not use single variable name as often as you do? I'm trying to do the "swap a skiplist" question, and the code on your Git contains so many single letter variables, it's very difficult to tell what's going on. Thank you for the clarification here though.

Comment: Note: it is **not** true that anything regarding trees takes O(log n). For example it's possible to implement the least-common ancestor of two nodes in time O(1)  (*constant time*, not amortized) for arbitrary trees (with some preprocessing). The log n time appears only when you have to walk down or up the tree.

Comment: @PatMorin how do you de-amortize in this case? Is it that you keep a doubled-size array, and then every time you add, you copy two more elements to the double-sized array? And once the single-sized array is filled then discard it and allocate a quad-sized array (which is constant time?) and so on?

Comment: @Jamie yes, that's the idea. Keep an array that's twice as big and, during each `add(x)` operation, copy two items from your primary array to this twice-big array. By the time you fill your primary array, everything has been copied to the twice-big array, so it becomes your primary array.   If you want to support more than just appending then you also have to make sure the contents of your twice-big array match those of your primary array and if you also want to support shrinking, then you also maintain a 2/3-size array that you switch to if your primary array becomes less than 1/3 full.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amortized Constant Time can almost always be considered equivalent to Constant Time, and without knowing the specifics of your application and the type of usage you are planning to do to this queue, most chances are that you will be covered.

An array list has the concept of *capacity*, which is basically equal to the largest size/length/count of items that has ever been required of it thus far.  So, what will happen is that in the beginning the array list will keep reallocating itself to increase its capacity as you keep adding items to it, but at some point the average number of items added per unit time will inevitably match the average number of items removed per unit time, (otherwise you would eventually run out of memory anyway,) at which point the array will stop reallocating itself, and all appends will be met at constant time of O(1).

However, keep in mind that by default, random removal from an array list is not O(1), it is O(N), because array lists move all the items after the removed item one position down to take the place of the removed item.  In order to achieve O(1) you will have to override the default behavior to replace the removed item with a copy of the last item of the array list, and then remove the last item, so that no items will be moved.  But then, if you do that, you do not exactly have a queue anymore.

Comment: Damn, good point on removals; I didn't consider that. And since we're randomly removing elements, doesn't that technically mean it's no longer a queue in that sense anyways?

Comment: Yes, it does mean that you are not really treating it as a queue. But I do not know how you are planning to find the items to remove.  If your mechanism of finding them expects them to be present in the queue in the order in which they were added, then you are out of luck.  If you do not care if the order of the items gets garbled, then you are fine.

Comment: The expectation is for my `RandomQueue` to implement the `Queue` interface, and for the supplied `remove` method to randomly remove instead of popping the head, so there shouldn't be any way to rely on a specific ordering. I think given the random nature of it then, that the user shouldn't expect it to keep any specific order. I quoted the assignment in my question for clarification. Thank you.

Comment: Yes then, it seems like you will be fine if you just make sure that item removal is done the way I suggested.

Comment: One last thing if you don't mind. I've thought it over more, and it doesn't seem like it's possible to have both "true" O(1) additions and "true" O(1) random removal; it'll be a tradeoff between the 2. You either have singly-allocated structure (like an array) that gives removal but not additon, or a chunk-allocated structure like a Linked-List that gives additions but not removal. Is this true? Again, thank you.

Comment: This is true only in a broad, generalizing sense.  With array lists this does not necessarily hold true, if you are willing to sacrifice the "ordered" property that array lists normally provide.  Which is okay for you, since you don't need this property.  Re-read my description of how to remove an item from the array list, and you will see that it is in fact O(1).  Let me know if there is some part of that description that you don't understand.

Comment: I'm saying that with an ArrayList, the removal *is* O(1) (if order doesn't matter), but that addition will always be Amortized O(1), and the near opposite is true for linked structures. It doesn't seem possible for both random removals and additions to both be O(1).

Comment: Well, you can remove head/tail in O(1) if you set it up as a ring-buffer. If you can mark an element as removed and change that to O(1+#removed), you can make the removal of any element O(1) by just marking it, even if the order must be preserved.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Whether removal can be described as O(1) in any sense depends upon how items are identified, and how removal affects the identities of items.  If the two operations one performs on a list are "add items to the end" and "iterate through all items and decide for each item whether to remove it", then a suitable-designed array list can perform the addition in time O(1) plus the time for an N-item array allocation every 1/N times the maximum size is increased, and perform the N-item scan-and-delete in time O(N) [so O(1) per element], even if the latter must keep items in order.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Having removal requests mark items as removed without necessarily deleting immediately them can be a good approach if one has addition operations scan part of the list for items that need to be "truly" deleted.  If each addition causes a two items to be examined and deleted if marked for removal, that will ensure that the maximum number of dead items will be limited to the maximum number of live items, while allowing both addition and deletion to remain O(1).  Such an approach can be especially nice in some multi-threaded scenarios...

Comment: ...where additions are all done by one thread, but multiple threads may need to "remove" items.  If the only effect of removing an item is to set a flag which is never written except to set it, then in some memory models, it's possible to avoid minimize synchronization delays (depending upon the memory model and exact requirements, one may be able to eliminate them entirely) in ways that would not be possible if deletes had to do more "work".

Answer (score 15):

The question seems to specifically ask for constant time, and not an [amortized constant time](http://mortoray.com/2014/08/11/what-is-amortized-time/). So with respect to the quoted question, no, they are not effectively the same*.  Are they however in real world applications?

The typical issue with amortized constant is that occasionally you have to pay the accumulated debt. So while inserts are generally constant, sometimes you have to suffer the overhead of reinserting everything again when a new block is allocated.

Where the difference between constant time and amortized constant time is relevant to an application depends on whether this occasional very slow speed is acceptable. For a very large number of domains this is generally okay. Especially if the container has an effective maximum size (like caches, temp buffers, working containers) you could effectively pay they costs only once during execution.

In response critical applications these times may be unacceptable. If you are required to meet a short time turnaround guarantee you cannot rely on an algorithm that will occasionally exceed that. I have worked on such projects before, but they are exceedingly rare.

It also depends on how high this cost actually is. Vectors tend to perform well since their reallocation cost is relatively low. If you go to hash map however, the reallocation can be a lot higher. Though again, for most applications probably fine, especially longer lived servers with an upper bound on the items in the container.

*There's a bit of an issue here though. In order to make any general purpose container be constant time for insertion one of two things must hold:

- The container must have a fixed maximum size; or
- you can assume memory allocation of individual elements is constant time.

Comment: "liver server" seems a strange phrasing to use here. Do you mean  "live server" perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

It depends – on whether you are optimizing for throughput or for latency:

- Latency-sensitive systems need consistent performance. For such a scenario, we have to emphasize worst-case behaviour of the system. Examples are soft real time systems such as games that want to achieve a consistent framerate, or web servers that have to send a response within a certain tight timeframe: wasting CPU cycles is better than being late.
- Throughput-optimized systems don't care about occasional stalls, as long as the maximal amount of data can be processed in the long run. Here, we are primarily interested in amortized performance. This is generally the case for number crunching or other batch-processing jobs.

Note that one system can have different components that must be categorized differently. E.g. a modern text processor would have a latency-sensitive UI thread, but throughput-optimized threads for other tasks such as spellchecking or PDF exports.

Also, algorithmic complexity often does not matter as much as we'd might think: When a problem is bounded to a certain number, then actual and measured performance characteristics are more important than the behaviour “for very large *n*”.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have very little background. The question ends with: "The add(x) and remove() operations in a RandomQueue should run in constant time per operation".

Comment: @Carcigenicate unless you know for a fact that the system is latency-sensitive, using amortized complexity to select a data structure should be absolutely sufficient.

Comment: I have the impression this might be a programming exercise or a test. And certainly not an easy one. Absolutely true that it very rarely matters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asked for an "amortized constant time" algorithm, your algorithm may *sometimes* take a long time. For example, if you use std::vector in C++, such a vector may have allocated space for 10 objects, and when you allocate the 11th object, space for 20 objects is allocated, 10 objects are copied, and the 11th added, which takes considerable time. But if you add a million objects, you may have 999,980 fast and 20 slow operations, with the average time being fast.

If you are asked for a "constant time" algorithm, your algorithm must *always* be fast, for every single operation. That would be important for real-time systems where you might need a guarantee that each single operation is *always* fast. "Constant time" is very often not needed, but it is definitely *not* the same as "amortized constant time".